# How to transfer data to controller as hash map from thymeleaf form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Please help me to solve this problem: I have no idea how to transfer data from thymeleaf view to controller, that expected data as a hash map? So let me explain in more detail.

I have next pojo, that is used as a wrapper for my hashMap data. It looks like this:

```
public class DTDays {
  private Map<Driver, String> driversDays = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<Driver, String> getDriversDays() {
      return driversDays;
  }

  public void setDriversDays(Map<Driver, String> driversDays) {
      this.driversDays = driversDays;
  }
}
```

Controller has method with parameter model attribute and another pojo:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/go", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String advanced(@ModelAttribute DTDays dtDays,
                       @RequestParam(name = "tourId") Long tourId, Model model){
    // make some business logic with provided data 
    return "redirect:/tours/advanced";
}
```

Here I debugged and `dtDays` is not null, but map property is empty, also tourId is worked as expected, I can get right value.

Now to the problem, view:

```
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <h1 th:text="${tour.tittle}"></h1>
    <p>Add tour interval for drivers</p>
    <form id="driverIntervals" th:action="@{/advanced/go}" th:object="${driversDays}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Drivers:</td>
                <td>Date:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="d: ${attachedDrivers}">
                <td th:text="${d.id+' '+d.fullName}" >
                    <input type="hidden" th:value="${d.id}" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick days" th:name="days"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" th:name="tourId" th:value="${tour.id}"/>
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

View looks like this:

[image: view]

What should i write in view to submit data? In my case Driver is a key of the map and user entered data in related input field will be a value of a map.

I already know how to submit List, by using select-option in a view:

```
<select th:name="drivers2attach" multiple="multiple" id="attachDrivers">
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="drivers" type="java.util.List<stanislav.tun.novinomad.picasso.persistance.pojos.Driver>"*/-->
    <option th:each="d : ${drivers}" th:value="${d.id}"
            th:text="${d.getId()+' '+d.fullName}">
    </option>
</select>
```

and  @RequestParam List list in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addTourAction(@ModelAttribute("tour") Tour tour,
@RequestParam(required = false, name = "drivers2attach") List<Long> drivers2attach)
```

**But how to deal with map?**

In case with list data is auto populated. In map only keys is prepopulated, this is count of drivers, and now i expect user input for each driver as a key value.

In researching of answers i already read these sources: 
[How to bind an object list with thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500731/how-to-bind-an-object-list-with-thymeleaf)

[Send list object from thymeleaf to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105188/send-list-object-from-thymeleaf-to-controller)

[How do I load HashMap and ModelandView object values using Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317170/how-do-i-load-hashmap-and-modelandview-object-values-using-thymeleaf-in-a-spring)

[Thymeleaf Map Form Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915358/thymeleaf-map-form-binding)

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-use-Map-lt-String-String-gt-with-Spring-and-Thymeleaf-forms-td4028666.html

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-use-method-POST-with-a-complex-Hashmap-lt-Object-list-lt-Object-gt-gt-td4031257.html

[Thymeleaf Map Form Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915358/thymeleaf-map-form-binding)

[Use HashMap as Form Backing Bean Spring MVC + ThymeLeaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284653/use-hashmap-as-form-backing-bean-spring-mvc-thymeleaf)
etc.

But didn't helps. Somewhere in this links I found out that I should use some wrapper to do it, but again no idea why it not works, or what should I do additionally for make it working. Maybe I generally make wrong logic and to submit data as hashmap I shall convert data to list first and then somehow get map from it in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for creating duplicate question, finally i found solution by following this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114294/9312168)

i wrote little project for test it and it works. So i was on right way in controller with a wrapper. I missed only view map representation and syntax;

Finally view will looks like this: 
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFF2b.png)

here is view source code:

```
<form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${form}" method="post">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div th:each="property : ${form.properties.entrySet()}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label th:for="*{properties['__${property.key}__']}" th:text="${property.key}">Property</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{properties['__${property.key}__']}" />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">send to controller</button>
```

and controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/save")
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute(name = "form") MapWrapper form){
    var mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("index");
    mav.addObject("mapWrapper", form);
    var map = form.getProperties();

    System.out.println("Size of map = "+map.size());
    for (Long id : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: "+id+"; Value: "+map.get(id));
    }

    return mav;
}
```

and output is :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBrWi.png)

P.S. reason of asking here is that i stuck on this problem for about 2 weeks, I despaired, but found solution after create a question.